# Phonegap/jsPDF issue saving html as pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm not a massive javascript/jquery user but I've started to get more into it for use in mobile apps... I've been looking for an answer to solve my problem of getting a blank page when trying to output html as a pdf using jspdf and every post I find has something to do with blobs.

this is my code I have that exports a blank pdf I have left the pdf.save in so I get an export on my PC as a sample of what it should look like but on my ipad and nexus 7 it saves a blank pdf.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter'), source = $('#home')[0], specialElementHandlers = {
    '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
        return true
    }
}
margins = {top: 80,bottom: 60,left: 40,width: 522};
pdf.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, {
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},
function (dispose) {
    pdf.save('home.pdf');
    console.log( pdfOutput );

    var pdfOutput = doc.output();
    console.log("file system - ");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

       console.log(fileSystem.name);
       console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
       console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

       fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
          var fileEntry = entry;
          console.log(entry);

          entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
             writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
             alert("write success");
          };

          console.log("writing to file");
             writer.write( pdfOutput );
          }, function(error) {
             console.log(error);
          });

       }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
       });
    },
        function(event){
            console.log( evt.target.error.code );
        });
  },
    margins
    )
```

Could someone give me a tip or point me in the right direction on how to incorporate your solution into my coding so I can save html formatting & images?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue.
Here's what I did to solve it.

**Replace the line**

`writer.write( pdfOutput );`

**with this:**

```
var data = pdfOutput;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}
writer.write(buffer);
```

Not 100% sure that I understand what's happening, but from what I have been researching, you need to convert the output from jsPDF to an ArrayBuffer before writing to the file.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply, I managed to get it to save on both the ipad & nexus 7 with & without your fix, I think I will go with your fix. But I now seem to be having an issue with the images in the html not saving as it should as well.

When exported & saved via desktop all images show perfectly but on the ipad and nexus 7 it's all distorted like the data wasn't read properly for the render of the file

Comment: did you by any change work on saving multiple html data into one pdf?

Comment: I also had the same issue with the html rendering. I opted for using the html2canvas js library to render the page accurately then store the entire render as an image inside the PDF. Otherwise you may need to look at the stackoverflow posts that discuss 'blob' creation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys, I got it to write the PDF perfectly. When it comes to organised formatting I used tables & span tags, but now that it works another issue has cropped up and this seems to be common... I don't know if it's ok for me to mention it here but it's for exactly the same thing.

This all works and saves the file perfectly on Android but on IOS the file is not saving because of the file system. Have you encountered this at all?

Comment: @AndreEtienne : can you plz post the working code for writing pdf on local storage.. I am trying but its not working

Answer (score 0):

@AdilWaqar I apologise for the delay in my response, I have been moving house. Below I have included the full javascript I finished on to get pdf printing working. it works perfect in android & IOS but the issue with IOS is that once the pdf has been generated you cannot gain access to it via a file manager.

The localStorage was used for storage before output, it has same id name on the span fields in the output html for that specific section, for example section 3 in the javascript had some signatures and some text boxes to output, the localStorage for one textfield in the output is...

```
getItem('cwiRiskAccesAsessName')
```

the html output is...

```
<tr><td>Assessor Name:</td><td><span id="EXPcwiRiskAccesAsessName"></span></td></tr>
```

I used jquery to pre-populate the span fields by building the html ready for output and adding a prefix to the id of each item, once done I used this simple line to deal with auto population on keyup. note: ignore 'inpt' in onkeyup, that was for a prefix within another part of the data handling function

```
onKeyUp="dataHandling(this,1,'inpt');"
var saveData = localStorage.setItem(source.id,source.value);var getData = localStorage.getItem(source.id);$("#EXP"+source.id).text(getData);
```

Below is the full pdf output javascript

```html
/* STORAGE-OUTPUT */
function storageOutput(){for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
 /* do something with localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));*/
 $("#storageHolder").append(localStorage.key(i)+'<br/>');}
}

/* SETUP */
function setup(){
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,onRequestFileSystemSuccess,null);
 
 function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
  var entry=fileSystem.root;entry.getDirectory("MAIN-DIRECTORY",{create:true,exclusive:false},onGetDirectorySuccess,onGetDirectoryFail);
 }
 function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir){}
 
 function onGetDirectoryFail(error){
  alert('Directory Setup Fail');}
 }/*CLEAR LOCALSTORAGE*/function clearLS(){
  localStorage.clear();alert(localStorage.length);
 }

function savePDF(id,filename) {
 
var folderName = 'MAIN-DIRECTORY/'+localStorage.getItem('householderAddress')+', '+localStorage.getItem('householderPostcode');
var saveData = localStorage.setItem('saveLocation',folderName);
var getData = localStorage.getItem('saveLocation');

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null); 

function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) { 
        var entry=fileSystem.root; 
        entry.getDirectory(getData, {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail); 
} 

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir){} 

function onGetDirectoryFail(error){} 
 
 if(id==1){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'),source = $('#savesec1')[0]
  , specialElementHandlers = {
   '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
    return true
   }
  }
 } else if (id==2){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'),source = $('#savesec2')[0]
  , specialElementHandlers = {
   '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
    return true
   }
  }
 } else if (id==3){
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'),source = $('#savesec3')[0]
  , specialElementHandlers = {
   '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
    return true
   }
  }
 }
 
  margins = {top: 40,bottom: 60,left: 40,width: 522};
 
  pdf.fromHTML(source, margins.left, margins.top, {
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   },
   function(dispose){
   /*SECTION 2*/
   if(id==2){
    pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('householderSig1'),'PNG',135,270,150,50);pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('assessSig1'),'PNG',135,410,150,50);
   }
   
   /*SECTION 3*/
   else if(id==3){
    pdf.addPage();pdf.setFontSize(15);pdf.setFontType("normal");pdf.text(20,30,'Assessor Name: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskAccesAsessName'));pdf.text(20,45,'Assessor Agency: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskAccesAsessAgency'));pdf.text(20,60, 'Date: '+localStorage.getItem('assessSig3Date'));pdf.text(20,75, 'Assessor Signature: ');pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('assessSig3'),'PNG',20,85,250,100);pdf.addPage();pdf.setFontSize(25);pdf.setFontType("normal");pdf.text(20,40,'Plan View:');pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('drawingOutput'),'PNG',20,40,500,500);pdf.addPage();pdf.setFontSize(15);pdf.setFontType("normal");pdf.text(20,30,'Front Elevation: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskFrontNotes'));pdf.text(20,430,'Rear Elevation: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskRearNotes'));pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskFrontOutput'),'PNG',40,40,500,350);pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskRearOutput'),'PNG', 40, 440, 500, 350);pdf.addPage();pdf.setFontSize(15);pdf.setFontType("normal");pdf.text(20,30,'Left Side Elevation: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskLeftNotes'));pdf.text(20,430,'Right Side Elevation: '+localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskRightNotes'));pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskLeftOutput'),'PNG',40,40,500,350);pdf.addImage(localStorage.getItem('cwiRiskRightOutput'),'PNG',40,440,500,350);
   }
    /* GENERIC IMAGE OUTPUT
    
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 40, 400, 400, 160);
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 40, 600, 400, 160);
    for (var i=0;i<dataSources.length;i++){ 
     pdf.addPage();
     alert(dataSources[i].text);
    }
    pdf.save(filename+'.pdf');*/
     var pdfOutput = pdf.output();
     //console.log( pdfOutput );
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {     
      
        fileSystem.root.getFile(getData+'/'+filename+'.pdf', {create: true}, function(entry) {
        var fileEntry = entry;
        //console.log(entry);
      
        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
        alert("PDF Saved Successfully");
        };
      
        console.log("writing to file");
        var data = pdfOutput;
        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
        var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        writer.write(buffer);
        }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
        });
      
        }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
        });
     },
     function(event){
      console.log( evt.target.error.code );
     });
   },
   margins
  )
}
```